# How should I be agnostic about whether something is a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to get the value of a property and then perform other logic with the value, but I'd like to support that property being a promise. What's the best way to support that while still supporting non promises?

```
// source can be an array of strings, a function, or a Promise
var source = this.cellProperties.source

if (typeof source === 'function') {
  sourceResult = source()
} else {
  sourceResult = source
}

sourceResult.then(function (options) {
  // perform logic with the value
  // but functions and strings don't have a `.then` property
})
```

The best idea I came up with was:

```
if (sourceResult.then === undefined) {
  sourceResult.then = function (callback) {
    callback(sourceResult)
  }
}
```

But there has to be a better approach than that, no?

Comment: Just make `sourceResult` a promise using `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: In all honesty, the actual solution here is not to allow three different input types in the function. Definitely _do not_ go with your idea of implementing promises (it'll break in several cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know whether the result is a `Promise` you can wrap it in one yourself using the `Promise.resolve()` function that returns a promise that is already resolved with the given value.

There's a minor (but probably negligible) overhead in wrapping a promise that is already one, but it's otherwise harmless - it just resolves to the same value as the original promise.

```
Promise.resolve(sourceResult).then(function (options) {
    // perform logic with the value
    ...
})
```

You will need to maintain your existing logic to obtain the result of `.source` if it's a function.

Comment: Uh... that's exactly what my answer says, 10 minutes after I posted and we discussed it. That's kinda not cool.

Comment: I posted it because I felt that your additional function `foo` was excessive in the circumstances - it's better just to inline the call to `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: Wrapper function or not is not even the key point of my answer; the key point is in the sentence of text that is above my code.

Comment: @Tomalak the key _word_ is "idempotent", but many people won't understand that.

Comment: Alnitak and @Tomalak, it's really atypical of you two to fight over something so meaningless. Please, let's keep the promise tag civil and not have these discussions in comments. Both your answers are different and both are correct (`Promise.resolve`).

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I'm marking this one as the "answer" to help anyone who stumbles upon here via google since the other answer required some reading of the replies to get the whole answer.

Answer (score 3):

Promises are idempotent, just take your incoming value and resolve a new promise with it:

```
function foo(valueOrPromise) {
    return Promise.resolve(valueOrPromise).then(function (value) {
        console.log("the value is: " + value);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("the error is: " + error);
    });
}
```

Comment: that won't work for the case when the given input is a function - he'll still need additional logic for that

Comment: Not sure what you mean, of course it will work: `foo(this.cellProperties.source).then(whatever);` Strictly speaking the function is not even necessary, a plain `Promise.resolve(this.cellProperties.source)` is enough.

Comment: `.source` might be a function

Comment: Oh, that. Under these circumstances the OP needs to do the `if (typeof this.cellProperties.source === 'function')` routine up-front, he has already figured out that part.